# How to change background color of page indicator in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I use a UIPageViewController in storyboard, and write a class inherit from UIPageViewController.

After I finished code, I found the background color of page indicator is black, which I don't know how to change.

[image]

I search the internet, and found many people will use UIViewController+UIPageControl to do custom page indicator.

Is it possible to change the background color in UIPageViewController?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

by adding:

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height*14/15, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height))
pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 147/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1)
view.addSubview(pageControl)
```

I've changed the color successfully.

But I've another question.

Although I've set the imageView to fill the full screen, the page control will cover the button of the image, how could I avoid page control cover the image, and only show the dots?

Comment: Since you have answered your own question please mark it accordingly. Also don't ask a new question in the answers or comments. Please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for over two hours. Here's what I did in Swift 4

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    for view in self.view.subviews{
        if view is UIPageControl{
            (view as! UIPageControl).currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .yellow
            }
        }
    }
```

Once you have the UIPageControl in this block, you should be able to customize its indicator colours